# Executing Local Query with loaded metadata fails

Tags: breeze

I'm new to breeze, this looks like a bug, but thought I'd ask here in case I just don't get it.

Setup loading metadata:

```
var metadataStore = new breeze.MetadataStore();
metadataStore.importMetadata(metadata);

queryOptions = new breeze.QueryOptions( {
    fetchStrategy: breeze.FetchStrategy.FromLocalCache
});

mgr = new breeze.EntityManager({
    serviceName: 'breeze',
    metadataStore: metadataStore,
    queryOptions: queryOptions
});
```

Executing local query explicitly works:

```
var q = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Boards")
            .toType('Board')
            .where('isImplicit', 'equals', withImplicits)
            .orderBy('name');

return manager.executeQueryLocally(q)  // returns result
```

But using `query.using` doesn't:

```
var q = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Boards")
    .toType('Board')
    .where('isImplicit', 'equals', withImplicits)
    .orderBy('name');

q = q.using(breeze.FetchStrategy.FromLocalCache)

return manager.executeQuery(q)
```

**UPDATE: To clarify, the above throws an error as it tries to fetchMetdata and there is no endpoint to fetch from. If I monkey patch the code below, it works fine. It seems like if the dataService `.hasServerMetadata`, you don't need to fetch it. I'm creating a test harness for a  breeze adapter, so I want to be able to run without the backend**

Looks like problem is [this line](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js/blob/7eb5deda8dfcff83ddf5a2cecf39ae21a9266a9b/src/a50_entityManager.js#L749) in EntityManager:

```
    if ( (!dataService.hasServerMetadata ) || this.metadataStore.hasMetadataFor(dataService.serviceName)) {
        promise = executeQueryCore(this, query, queryOptions, dataService);
    } else {
        var that = this;
        promise = this.fetchMetadata(dataService).then(function () {
            return executeQueryCore(that, query, queryOptions, dataService);
        });
    }
```

I believe line should be `if( dataService.hasServerMetadata || ...`, but being new to Breeze thought I'd ask here before opening GH issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*EntityManager.executeQueryLocally* is a synchronous function and you can use its result immediately. i.e.

```
var myEntities = myEntityManager.executeQueryLocally(myQuery);
```

Whereas *EntityManager.executeQuery* is an asynchonous function ( even if the query has a 'using' call that specifies that this is a local query).  So you need to call it like this:

```
var q2 = myQuery.using(breeze.FetchStrategy.FromLocalCache);
myEntityManager.executeQuery(q2).then(function(data) {
  var myEntities = data.results;
});
```

The idea behind this is that with *executeQuery* you treat all queries in exactly the same fashion, i.e. asynchronously, regardless of whether they are actually asynchronous under the hood.

If you want to create an EntityManager that does not go to the server for metadata you can do the following:

```
 var ds = new breeze.DataService({
   serviceName: "none",
   hasServerMetadata: false
 });

 var manager = new breeze.EntityManager({
   dataService: ds
 });
```

Comment: Yes, I understand the difference and I want to use the second format precisely for the reason you specify. I just want to confirm that it's a bug that it doesn't work when loaded manually with metadata and running purely local.

Comment: Sorry, I must be missing something...  I do not understand what you think the bug is. 'return manager.executeQuery(q)' will always return a Promise and not actual entities.  What error are you seeing?

Comment: Sorry about that Jay, added some more detail. Basically I'm creating a test harness and want to run without a server.

Comment: Ok, I just updated my earlier answer to show how to create an EntityManager that DOES not try to fetchMetadata.  Also see: http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/load-metadata-script

Comment: Oh, I get it now, totally obvious - I think I saw that initially then forgot about it - thanks!